# RMI - references and using remote object as a "key" in a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, rmi

I have an RMI server which exports objects which implement an interface, let's call it "TestInterface".

The client can then do various tasks, calling methods on this interface. I then have some other interface for a different type of object, for which one of the methods takes in a object of type "TestInterface". The method tries to use a hashmap where the "TestInterface" is the key (it stores a hashmap of all "TestInterface" objects on the server, the value being what I would like to retrieve), but fails to find it. I know this key exists within the hashmap, but due to the interface being passed to the client, and then back to the server later it seems to not find it.

I know it exists as I am able to print out the IDs of the objects which are keys in the hashmap, and the ID of the "TestInterface" passed in (they are the same). I then printed them both out (using the default toString), and I get this:

```
Proxy[TestInterface,RemoteObjectInvocationHandler[UnicastRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[127.0.0.1:1099](remote),objID:[-38c943f9:14be569cb95:-7ff9, 8183237023004091504]]]]]

Test[UnicastServerRef [liveRef: [endpoint:[127.0.0.1:1099](local),objID:[-38c943f9:14be569cb95:-7ff9, 8183237023004091504]]]]
```

I can see these are different, which is probably why I cannot look them up. However, they look to be pointing to the same object (I believe this is the case as the objectId is the same).

My question is, why can I not look up this "Key" in the hashmap, where the Key is a reference to the same object.

My second question is, is there an easy way to fix this?

Comment: I don't see why you're doing any of this. If the client already has the TestInterface stub, why isn't he calling methods on it directly? Instead of passing it back to you and asking you to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is occurring because the actual object which you are using as the key does not evaluate the same with `hashCode()` and `equals()`.  Those are the methods the `HashMap` is using for the lookup.  A common way to handle this is to create a wrapper class which will use the internal `objId` inside the `hashCode()` and `equals()`.  This wrapper class is then used as the key to the map.

Something like:

```
public Wrapper {
  private Keyclass key;
  ...

  public Keyclass getWrapped() { return key; }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return key.objID.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return key.objID.equals(((Wrapped)o).key.objID);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is spot on. I thought it would be something like this. Thank you!

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. Both generated and dynamic stubs have well-defined semantics for `equals()` and `hashCode()`.